# Is it possible to make a Web link which will determine the default value in a drop down on the target page?

Tags: http

I want to create multiple links to the same page,  with each one having the drop down menu populate with a different value upon landing.

So link one would have the drop down populate "tom", link two "dick", and three "harry".

Is this possible, and if so how do you do it? I can't see anything similar but I may also be failing in my Google-fu.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: no this is not possible. W3C prohibit such web links due to the fact that far too much of the internet is populated with "two dicks" and "three harrys" . Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a GET request to each link, which can tell the new page what value to start on, for example you can link to:

`destination.php?start=Tom`

and on the PHP at the destination you can get the `$_GET['start']` value and use it to set a `selected=selected` value in the HTML `<select>` statement on the new page.

Your question is somewhat ambiguous but I think this is the answer you need?